# How to detect when a Beacon is no longer detected by an iOS device?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I am running into an issue when ranging beacons using `LocationManager.startRangingBeacons` method.

When ranging for Beacons, the Apple documentation clearly states that [locationManager(_:didRange:satisfying:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/3240610-locationmanager) should be called when a Beacon is detected, and also that [locationManager(_:didFailRangingFor:error:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/3240609-locationmanager) should be called when a Beacon is not detected.

I have implemented both of those methods:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRange beacons: [CLBeacon], satisfying beaconConstraint: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint) {
    print("Beacon detected: \(beaconConstraint)")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailRangingFor beaconConstraint: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint, error: Error) {
    print("Beacon not detected: \(beaconConstraint)")
}
```

The first one (didRange) is periodically called every time the device is near a Beacon, as expected. However, when Beacon is no longer detected, the `didFailRangingFor` is never called. Why is this not working as explained in the documentation?

Comment: Seems like `didFailRanging` is only called when there are no beacons at all, is that your case?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Yes, I only have one beacon at the moment of testing, and when I turn it off, or put it out of range, the didRange stops being called, but didFailRangingFor does not get called.

Answer (score 0):

The method `didFailRanging` **is not called** under normal circumstances if no beacons are detected.  It is only called if an error condition (e.g. bluetooth is off, permissions are not granted, airplane mode) prevents detecting beacons at all.

When using ranging APIs, **if no beacons are detected under normal circumstances, you simply get a call to the `didRange` delegate method with a zero length array** of `CLBeacon` objects.  There is a ~5 second memory to this array, so any beacons detected in the last 5 seconds will still show up, even if they are briefly not visible.  but brief dropouts of over 5 seconds may still cause false reports that beacons are not visible using this technique.

For more stability, you  may want to try using monitoring APIs, which are better suited for this use case (try `CLLocationManager` method `startMonitoring(for: CLRegion)`.

If no beacons are detected, you will get a call to the `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLRegion)` method of `CLLocationManagerDelegate` (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423570-locationmanager)) with a `CLRegionState.outside` value.  This only happens if no beacons are detected in over 30 seconds.

Comment: Hm, I'd say that's a flaw in Apple's documentation then. They make it sound like the `didFailRanging` gets called simply when beacon is not detected.

However, even the `didRange` method is not behaving correctly for me. When beacon is not detected, it simply does not get called at all, which makes it hard for me to actually know when beacons are detected or not.

The monitoring API isn't useful for me as it requires background location permission to function, and also according to documentation, it's slower to detect beacons.

Comment: If you do not see didRange get called once per second while the app is in the foreground, then something is wrong.  Do you see it gat called at all?  How often?